# Is there a way to change the appearance of LyX output with change tracking (or alter the commands in LaTeX)?

Tags: pdf, lyx

I tend to use LyX for composing scientific papers, but a journal wants me to have changed text marked in specific ways that don't happen to be the way that LyX translates tracked changes into PS/PDF.

Is there a way to modify not just the color but also the underlining of changed text when it's converted to PS or PDF?  I suppose I'd have to do something with the `\lyxadded` and/or `\lyxdeleted` commands?

LyX seems to always generate commands that look like `\lyxadded{My Name,,,}{2011 blah blah date}{my text}`, so if there's a good way to intercept this and add my own formatting to the `{my text}` part, that would probably work if there's no more elegant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't want to get fancy with detecting whether changed text should be viewed on the output or not, it's actually quite simple.  LyX writes the `\lyxadded` command into its own preamble in the generated .tex file:

```
\newcommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\color{lyxadded}{}#3}}
```

and this preamble occurs *before* the one it gives to you under Document / Settings ... / LaTeX Preamble.  So all you have to do is redefine the command:

```
\renewcommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\color{lyxadded}\uline{#3}}}
```

Since LyX already uses the ulem package for striking out changes, `\uline` is available without any additional `usepackage`ing.

If you go this route, you're probably best off leaving the "show changes" on every time you export, and just renew the `\lyxadded` and `\lyxdeleted` commands as appropriate when you don't want to see them.